# Присвоение уникального ID="id" через JS и Django

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Всем привет, у меня такой вопрос как я могу через присвоить атрибут к div?

```
<div id=">> Присвоить ID из js <<">
...
</div>
```

> Присвоить ID из js 
...

Answer (score 1):

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div'); // Впишите нужный селектор чтобы найти div
div.id = 'my-new-id'; // Задаём id
console.log(div); // Демонстрируем div в консоли
```

```html
<div>123</div>
```